# Javascript: object from array, what contains object with id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {id: 32, color: 'ff00dd'},
  {id: 64, color: 'ab230b'},
  {id: 102, color: '5f561d'}
]
```

How can I convert it to this format:

```
{ 32: 'ff00dd', 64: 'ab230b', 102: '5f561d'}
```

([LoDash](https://lodash.com/) is useable)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might I ask why you are tending towards that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using lodash:

```
_.zipObject(_.pluck(a, 'id'), _.pluck(a, 'color'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Without LoDash, a simple `for` loop can do this for us:

```js
var data = [
    {id: 32, color: 'ff00dd'},
    {id: 64, color: 'ab230b'},
    {id: 102, color: '5f561d'}
  ],
  obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    obj[data[i].id] = data[i].color;

console.log(obj);
```

```html
Open your JavaScript console to see the result.
```

The output of the console logging in the above snippet is:

```
> Object {32: "ff00dd", 64: "ab230b", 102: "5f561d"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the objects in your array and then add each as a property on a new object:

```
var data = [
  {id: 32, color: 'ff00dd'},
  {id: 64, color: 'ab230b'},
  {id: 102, color: '5f561d'}
];
var newObject = {};

_(data).forEach(function(obj) {
    newObject[obj.id] = obj.color;
});
```